# Visual studio localhost crashes after callback from facebook app login

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, facebook, visual-studio-2008, facebook-fql

I am trying to login into my site through facebook app. Previously it worked well with my localhost. But suddenly from today localhost crashes after successfull callback from facebook. Url after callback is:

> =">http://localhost:50834/mysite/callbacks/fb.aspx?code=AQDksBPPypmUMqH8svoWDxysd48pPI3sZbRTUJLG6naz3QjgaHXpUwPiL6InkxG_stSz6weZGV9OIf97fEuAPKYPSWNUbfEL7A4OcKtu3clNxdH0GLuZCuROZO46XZ2arbabTgnia3okYfHfy-LU1Hf8LRfaMrAAAjRG_gaMWGSaBHoqnubDVbhqZj12IsJjIhvK2tHg_MAqYM7V6e8MGRW5qWkbrOLpCb1652w0Uxa1co0sI_qbEY_-KdRxwQQRprzeG8JL0XMNNMdONA8aTzPWm4lajhcSZXqTrEEK8aww22_4-G0FrN4JTrQ6u1ZyqJE#*=*

Response from the browser:

> Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:50834

I could not log anything since the url above is not executed due to the crash immediately after callback. Any solution please?

Comment: What do the server’s log files say?

Comment: Could you please suggest me how could I see the server log in vs studio embedded server?

Comment: Right now it is now working without any modifications in any part of the code. I am worried I cannot find any reason for this. Don't know if problem was from facebook's side. I was suffering same problem with paypal also which is also now working without any contribution from my side.